# Is there a way to specify the field-key when using the INTO statement?

Tags: time-series, influxdb, influxql

I have the need to combine two measurements into one single measurement for cross-measurement operations, but both of the measurements only have one single field-key "value".

(I know, that this is not a "pretty" Schema Design and I know about Flux query language but I am not allowed to use Beta features in this case.)

**Example:**

Base Series:

```
voltage, field-key: "value"=x,<tags>
current, field-key: "value"=x,<tags>
```

Should become this:

New Series

```
newMeasurement,field-key: "current"=x,field-key: "voltage"=x, <tags>
```

I tried `SELECT_clause INTO <measurement_name> FROM_clause [WHERE_clause] [GROUP_BY_clause]` but I could not achieve the desired result.
Is this possible or do I have to re-arrange my schema and rename field-keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try
`SELECT value AS current INTO newMeasurement FROM current GROUP BY *`
`SELECT value AS voltage INTO newMeasurement FROM voltage GROUP BY *`
?

Comment: Works fine! Thank you!